# ¿Cómo obtener valores especificos de un array multidimensional asociativo en laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, array

Necesito obtener unos valores específicos de un array que estoy creando.

**Controlador**

```
public function index(Evento $evento, Request $request)
    {
        $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
        dd(\Session::get('tienda'));
        return view('tienda.tienda', compact('tienda'));
}
/* Primero agrego el evento */

public function agregar(Evento $evento){

    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    if ($tienda = null) {
        $tienda = $evento;
        \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
        return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
    }
    else{

        \Session::forget('tienda');
         $tienda = $evento;
        \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
        return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
    }
}

/* Luego agrego otro array inscrito con otros valores */

public function inscribir(Evento $evento, Request $request){
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    $inscrito = Inscrito::create($request->all());
    $store = $tienda['id'];
    $inscrito->eventos()->attach($store);
    $tienda[$inscrito['cedula']] = $inscrito;
    Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
    Session::save('tienda', $tienda);
    return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));


}
```

Esto me muestra el array de inscrito dentro del array tienda y se me van sumando cada vez que inscribo una nueva persona, lo que necesito es recorrer los datos de las personas para mostrar los valores de cada inscrito.

Intento llegar a esos valores de la siguiente manera, pero nada:

```
@foreach($tienda as $key => $value )

    <td>{{ $value['cedula'] }}</td>

@endforeach
```

El dd me muestra que queda asi:

[image: Resultados del DD]

Y si pueden me aclaran lo siguente, si estoy confundido, entiendo que esto genera un array multidimensional asociativo asi, es correcto?:

```
['id'=>'id','nombre'=>'nombre'....cedula=>[id'=>'id','nombre'=>'nombre'...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien tu problema, lo que pasa es que tienes una instancia del objeto "Inscrito", no un array:

```
@foreach($tienda as $key => $value )

    <td>{{ $value->cedula }}</td>

@endforeach
```

**Edición después de revisar con más detalle el `dd()`:**

La forma directa para acceder lo que muestras (sin el foreach) sería:

```
{{ $tienda->['24577085']->cedula }}
```

Si quieres utilizar un foreach, idealmente tendrías que reorganizar un poco la forma como almacenas las instancias de Inscrito, pues sería más fácil tener una propiedad "inscritos", la cual al no tener valor dinámico como lo es el número de cédula, la puedes referenciar más fácilmente:

```
@foreach($tienda->inscritos as $key => $value )

    <td>{{ $value->cedula }}</td>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Gracias por responder de nuevo Shaz, no me deja acceder igual, en mi poco conocimiento creo que es porque no es una propiedad de ese objeto, creo que si es un array solo que esta almacenado en una variable de session... y forma parte del array principal que es $tienda como un attributtes... he intentado casi todo lo que conozco para acceder con dobles foreach y recorrer las claves, recorrer los valores hasta con 3 foreach para probar jajaja

Comment: Bueno, lo que pasa es que no entiendo en qué punto haces el dd(), por eso quedé un poco perdido cuando redactaba la respuesta.

Comment: jajaja lo siento, bueno lo hago en otro metodo desde donde intento acceder, desde el metodo index le mando la variable $tienda con session::get, al Session:get es al que le hago el dd

Comment: Por favor muéstralo en la pregunta, yo no conozco tu proyecto y no es evidente para mí que pretendes mostrar y donde... estamos disparando al aire.

Comment: ¿La variable tienda almacena una instancia de Evento? El problema es que  no se entiende si el dd viene de la vista o el controlador e igualmente si ese fragmento de blade forma parte de cuál vista...

Comment: Ya agregue el metodo por el cual envio la variable $tienda al index, y alli es donde le hago el dd, ahora la variable tienda almacena una session a la cual le actualizo le voy añadiendo los array que necesito. a su vez esa variable tiene los datos de los inscritos y de los eventos

Comment: A que te refieres con re organizar la forma en como almaceno la instancia de inscrito? Alguna idea? lo que me interesa es que se almacen varios inscritos en el mismo array para despues mostrar los datos que a placer en cualquier parte... Agradeceria mucho la ayuda Shaz...

Comment: No sé hasta que punto necesites almacenar instancias de objetos en la sesión y agregar propiedades que contienen otros objetos, me parece un poco extraño eso, pero realmente depende de tu diseño. Para resolverlo fácil con lo que ya tienes, simplemente puedes hacer algo así para agrupar los inscritos: `$tienda['inscritos'][$inscrito['cedula']] = $inscrito;` y revisa la edición (al final).